# Review audit exposes the actual question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review, review-audits

I was reviewing close votes when I found that the trick review test showed modified scores and details and if you open the question link on new tab, you can view the actual question.

If you get to see the question on which the test was based, it reveals its a trick review. Should this be fixed? Perhaps a fake link for the fake question?

This is the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/2583916) where I found this.

> ### Congratulations!
>
> This was only a test, designed to make sure you were paying attention. You passed. For reasonable questions, Leave Open is appropriate.

Comment: That is how audits work. Community wants to stop robo-reviewers.

Comment: If you stopped on an audit, clicked through and saw the actual question, then the audit has served its purpose.

Comment: In other words, the purpose of review audits is to catch robo-reviewers who just blindly click the "Approve" button. If you're paying enough attention to try to beat the system, you're good.